# Convert int to bytes - different result in Java & Actionscript

Tags: java, actionscript, integer, byte

I would like to convert integers to bytes. I have an example in Actionscript and I need to convert it to Java. For the sake of simplicity let's assume only one number, 1234. This is my Java code:

```
int[] a = {1234};
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(a.length * 4);
IntBuffer intBuffer = byteBuffer.asIntBuffer();
intBuffer.put(a);
byte[] array = byteBuffer.array();
for (int i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
    Log.i(T, i + ": " + array[i]);
}
```

This gives me the following result:

```
0 : 0
1 : 0
2 : 4
3 : -46
```

While in Actionscript I have this:

```
var c:ByteArray = new ByteArray;
c.writeInt(1234);
for(var p:uint=0; p<c.length; p++) {
    trace(p+" : "+c[p]);
}
```

And the result:

```
0 : 0
1 : 0
2 : 4
3 : 210
```

What am I doing wrong, why is the result different? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java uses **unsigned** bytes.

ActionScript probably **signed** by default.

```
3 : -46 //signed
3 : 210 //unsigned
```

This can print every byte as unsigned:

```
System.out.println((b < 0 ? 256 + b : b));
```

Answer (score 2):

In java a byte is always considered as signed when converted to another type.  Thats why you see a negative number.

Try:

```
Log.i(T, i + ": " + (array[i] & 0xff))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you convert `-46 to a hex` you'll get `0xD2` wich can be converted back to a decimal of `210`.
that's the difference between unsigned and signed integers.

so the result indeed is equal (equal, not identical though)
As long as both codes produce the same byte (D2) you're good to go.

Oh, if you're unsure, just let both codes provide either the hex value not the decimal value of the result or make sure both return either signed or unsigned integers, and not as above, then you'll get identical results ;)

for example check c in actionscript
with those methods:

```
readInt()
and
readUnsignedInt()
```

you should see that readint returns -46 and readunsignedint 210