# Integer.toHexString in Python

Tags: python

Here I have java code

```
static String md5(byte[] bArr) {
    MessageDigest instance = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    instance.update(bArr);
    byte[] digest = instance.digest();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (byte b : digest) {
        sb.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xffffffff));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

calling `md5("A".getBytes())`, I got

```
7fffffffc56270ffffffe7ffffffa7fffffffa81a5935ffffffb72effffffacffffffbe29
```

How can I achieve the same result by Python?
I tried to use the following

```
m = hashlib.md5()
m.update(str.encode('utf-8'))
bytes = m.digest()
return ''.join('{:02x}'.format(x) for x in bytes)
```

I got

```
7fc56270e7a70fa81a5935b72eacbe29
```

which is the same with `m.hexdigest()`

Edit:
The issue looks with those "negative" bytes in between.
e.g
second byte is "-59" in int in Java but Python doesn't somehow recognize
and 5th byte is "-25"

Those 'f's are because these are negative.

Comment: Maybe try {:04x} in the last line. Anyway, the java code is wrong, it prints every byte as an integer, which results in all of these fffff in the hex digest. That's something you probably don't want.

Comment: 04x is padding 0 in front:
007f00c50062007000e700a7000f00a8001a0059003500b7002e00ac00be0029

Comment: I'll second what Tomer says, the Python code looks sane (especially `m.hexdigest()`), the Java code is weird, padding every byte with three extra useless bytes. Replicating the Java code would mean getting Python do do it in the same weird way as well.

Comment: @Amadan the python code has to replicate it otherwise: java bytes are signed so `& 0xff` is what one would normally use to take the one's complement, turning a signed byte into the corresponding unsigned one (e.g. -5 -> 251), which of course requires widening to a short ot integer as Java *doesn't have unsigned types*.  Python's bytes are not signed.

Comment: Conceptually a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720587/convert-int-to-bytes-different-result-in-java-actionscript/14720627#14720627

Answer (score 0):

The java version is... weird. It takes every byte, widens it to an integer, then takes the one's complement *of the integer* and formats that. It's like a broken version of making signed bytes unsigned.

Which is completely unnecessary in the first place in Python since bytes are always unsigned. But if you *really* want it, you can just format `x | 0xffffff00` to hex (it's going to "pad" the byte with 6 `ff`s).

Comment: But do that only to the "negative" bytes, i.e. those with values >= 0x80

Comment: Not sure where to apply x | 0xffffff00, if
return ''.join('{:02x}'.format(x|0xffffff00) for x in bytes)
it gets different result